# DialogBox in web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dialog

Is there a DialogBox to web where can select a font like that in winApplication?

I need to let the user select a font from the fonts that have to everyone like in windos application

Comment: you will need the text editors. [Here is a link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx)

Comment: Done a quick google search and found nothing at all..

Comment: this might be a help    [link](http://s3.amazonaws.com/jquery-font-chooser/examples/example.html)

Comment: What should happen with the Font that is selected, should it be selected and used in an Textfield, or should the Website be rerendered with it, or should it be uploaded, ... ? And whicht fonts should be selectable, installed fonts, specific fonts, all webfonts, ...?